# Can't see "Escape" colors in terminal

Tags: macos, shell, colors, terminal, iterm

can someone help me i don't know how to get this working.
I can't see "escape" colors or i don't know how they are called in my terminal:

http://cl.ly/image/0U3N0Z2M2q2m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tpb.sh` just prints the contents of what was output to your terminal, the simplest way is probably to do:

```
echo -e "$(./tpb.sh)"
```

The `-e` option enables the interpretation of backslashed escapes by `echo`.